# How to make OpenDialog show modal in Firemonkey?

Tags: delphi, modal-dialog, delphi-xe2, firemonkey, fileopendialog

When I'm calling an OpenDialog from my form on ButtonClick event. The dialog does not shows as modal and is also displays in taskbar (in WindowsXP). I can return to main form and click Open again and again - popping up several dialogs at once..

How do I make an OpenDialog to be modal in Firemonkey?
Is it specifically made so that no modal dialogs are allowed due to multi-platform anture of FM?

**EDIT:** The bug is fixed in Update 3.

Comment: Just done a lot of experimenting on your behalf, and there appears to be no way to make it Modal. Not only that, but it appears as though it makes a request for the Platform to produce the Open Dialog and display it, which seems to operate on a separate thread.

The best I can come up with at this stage is to Hide the form, Execute the Open Dialog, then Show the form afterward.

It sucks, but that's one way!

Comment: Alternatively, you can have a transparent Panel overlay the controls of the form (or disable each control), perhaps add a Blur effect to the form, execute the open dialog, then undo those changes after the dialog closes.

Neither of these are elegant solutions, though.

Comment: Thank for your response and effort!

Comment: I recommend posting your problem on QC! Do that, post the link here... and I'll try to put some focus on it with Embarcadero for you.
This is actually a major flaw in my opinion! A Dialog is useless if it's not modal, and this behaviour inexplicably breaks the linear execution model!

Comment: To my regret I don't have QC account yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's a bug. There are a lot of modal type bugs with FireMonkey, and hopefully they will be fixing them soon. Currently, even modal forms aren't modal.

For your problem, I have a workaround for Windows, but you might not like it.

You need to fix the following line in the TPlatformWin.DialogOpenFiles() method in FMX.Platform.Win.

Under `with OpenFile do` change:

```
hwndOwner := 0;
```

To this:

```
hWndOwner := FmxHandleToHWND(Application.MainForm.Handle);
```

The function utilizes the Windows `GetOpenFileName` API call, even though it's deprecated on Vista and above. If a owner handle is passed in, the dialog is modal, otherwise it's not.

You might want to submit this as a bug to qc.embarcadero.com along with the workaround.